# $timeout fails in global service

Tags: angularjs

see http://plnkr.co/edit/FiTKFHV9f1P1N8NgcC5K for an example. the error is

TypeError: number is not a function
    at Object.$rootScope.alerts.push.timeout

The similar close function which does not contain a timeout does not fail.

Answer (score 1):

The local variable `$timeout` hides the `$timeout` module.

Change

```
add: function (type, msg, duration, $timeout)
```

to

```
add: function (type, msg, duration)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just misspelled the name of variable in the declaration of `timeout` in `alertService`.

You passed `$index` as `$timeout` variable in `alert.timeout` function, so the `$timeout` is not actually a `$timeout` service from angularjs, instead it's a number (passed index of element in iteration).

Comment: There is no misspelling of timeout that I can find.

Comment: the $index is the index into the alerts array of the selected row of the alerts. it has no effect on the $timeout function itself this is traceable with chrome dev tools for example

Comment: Change the code to something like `timeout: function($timeout) {
                    console.log($timeout);` and you will get the problem.

Comment: continued research from that point caused me to find $timeout in                add: function(type, msg, duration, $timeout) { changed to               add: function(type, msg, duration) {
 and it now seems to work